# Failed to start bean kafkaListenerContainer: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-kafka

I am using [this](https://github.com/iainporter/spring-file-poller) as example for reading file using spring integration, its working fine but when I try to send file to kafka producer it doesn't work. I tried to look up this issue on internet but could not find help.
Here is my code:

file: MessageProcessingIntegrationFlow.java:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow writeToFile() {
return IntegrationFlows.from(ApplicationConfiguration.INBOUND_CHANNEL)
       .transform(m -> new StringBuilder((String)m).toString().toUpperCase())
//                .handle(fileWritingMessageHandler)
    .handle(loggingHandler())
    .handle(kafkaProducerMessageHandler())
    .get();
}



 //producing channel
@Bean(name="kafkaChannel")
public DirectChannel kafkaChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public DirectChannel consumingChannel() {
  return new DirectChannel();
}


    @Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "kafkaChannel")
public MessageHandler kafkaProducerMessageHandler() {
    KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> handler =
            new KafkaProducerMessageHandler<>(kafkaTemplate());
    handler.setTopicExpression(new LiteralExpression(kafkaTopic));
    handler.setMessageKeyExpression(new LiteralExpression("kafka-integration"));
    return handler;
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
  return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
  return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
}

@Bean
public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
  Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
  properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
  properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
  properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
  // introduce a delay on the send to allow more messages to accumulate
  properties.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 1);

  return properties;
}

//consumer configuration....
@Bean
public KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String> kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter() {
  KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String> kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter =
      new KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<>(kafkaListenerContainer());
  kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(consumingChannel());
  return kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Bean
public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> kafkaListenerContainer() {
  ContainerProperties containerProps = new ContainerProperties(kafkaTopic); //set topic name
  return (ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>) new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>(
      consumerFactory(), containerProps);
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<?, ?> consumerFactory() {
  return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
}

@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
  Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
  properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
  properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
  properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
  properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "helloworld");
  // automatically reset the offset to the earliest offset
  properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

  return properties;
}
```

Here is stacktrace:

```
 org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'kafkaListenerContainer'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaDataListener implementation must be provided
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:348) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:151) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:114) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at com.porterhead.Application.main(Application.java:25) [classes/:na]
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaDataListener implementation must be provided
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:92) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:199) ~[spring-kafka-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
... 12 common frames omitted
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please do let me know if you need more details on this one.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `KafkaProducerMessageHandler` is one-way component, it doesn’t produce reply. It just publishes to Kafka topic and does nothing more. Therefore you can’t continue flow after it like you do with your `handle(loggingHandler())`. The `KafkaProducerMessageHandler` must be the last endpoint in the flow. Unlike with the `FileWritingMessageHandler` which is a `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler` and continue the flow.

Nevertheless consider in the future to properly describe the problem: what is expected and what is wrong. The answer was my best guess because I know the code of all those components.

Comment: I wanted to read file and sent it to kafka producer, is there any other way I can send data to kafka?

Comment: We got it, but what is the problem though. We can’t speculate here when there is no particular issue. And also: there is nobody here to write code for you. That’s out of our responsibility.

Comment: You just need to remove `handle(loggingHandler())` from your flow. It’s also one-way and can’t be in the middle of flow

Comment: I removed loggingHandler(), see the edited question. Thanks.

Comment: You use old Spring Boot . It isn’t compatible with that Spring Kafka `1.2.2`. Consider to switch to the latest: https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/. You need Spring Framework `4.3.x` there already

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert `MessageListener<String, String>` into `ContainerProperties`.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Bean
public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> kafkaListenerContainer() {
  ContainerProperties containerProps = new ContainerProperties(kafkaTopic); //set topic name
  containerProps.setMessageListener((MessageListener<String, String>) message -> { });
  return (ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>) new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>(
      consumerFactory(), containerProps);
}
```